# Generating ActivityTracing Event Logs on Windows

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, event-log

I'm currently working on a (C++) application that is trying to feed on system wide events through Windows` event log.

I am using the `EvtSubscribe` API which is described very nicely by MSDN.
Everything works fine and I successfully receive notifications for any event that occurs.

What bothers me is that I stumbled upon a web reference that describes an event type I never saw beforehand: '**Activity Tracing**'.

All the other (Critical, Error, Information, etc.) event types are acquired using the `EvtRender` API and `EvtSystemLevel`/`EvtSystemKeywords` getters.

Google searches were full of false positives, since the keywords 'Activity' and 'Tracing' are reused for multiple applications and infrastructures.

My best lead came from a [reference](https://sourceforge.net/p/snare/discussion/134533/thread/906b3c1d/) we found, written by a user of a different event logging collection framework:

> Microsoft use it to troubleshoot aplications.
>
> Negotiation/SCT exchange. This can happen at the transport later (through
>   binary data exchange) or message layer (through SOAP message exchanges).
>   Message encryption/decryption, with signature verification and authentication.
>   Traces appear in the ambient activity, typically "Process Action."
>
> Authorization and verification. This can happen locally or when communicating
>   between endpoints.
>
> Using Tracing to Troubleshoot Your Application http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738639.aspx
>
> Activity Tracing in Message Security http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738609.aspx

When I tried to examine these links I saw that this tracing mechanism allows troubleshooting of WCF applications.

But, since I'm no expert of WCF to say the least, I don't want to spend days on setting up a .NET environment and brute forcing sample WCF applications to enables this feature and trigger such event logs.

Could anyone recommend a quick way of generating such an Event Log?

Comment: I am inferring a lot by your questions context  but you might be interested in knowing the following exists within the windows OS as an FYI.   It is called Event Tracing for Windows or ETW    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can configure WCF tracing as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing.  This is all configuration, no coding necessary

When you configure the Listener, you can use the EventLogTraceListener.  That will produce the Activity Tracing events.

Comment: I know this is all the configuration that is required, but you have to configure your own WCF project, and make it work so the events are emitted. I don't have such a project, and I wanted a shortcut instead of creating one by my own, configuring it and playing with it... I'm sure there are apps out there I could just download and run to trigger these events.

Comment: OK, then I have never seen a application that creates these events just to have them created, especially to EventQueue by default.